# empty list on calling a function twice

Tags: python, list, function

When i make call to the `get_all_predicates` function to get the `Predicate_List`, I get the correct values. But when the `get_all_predicates` function is called at `print(get_all_predicates(examples))`, I get an empty list back.

```
def get_all_predicates(examples):
        return [d['Predicate'] for d in examples]

Predicate_list = list(set(get_all_predicates(examples)))
print(get_all_predicates(examples))
```

Example below contains a list of values returned from a generator function.

```
examples = get_examples(values, name)
def get_examples(list, attributes):
        for value in list:
            yield dict(zip(attributes, value.strip().replace(" ", "").split(',')))
```

Comment: @vaultah I just edited. sorry for being brief.

Comment: Once again, what is `get_examples`? In order for us to help, please include a minimal, runnable, code in your question

Comment: The generator is exhausted, it has to be re-initialized.

Comment: @cricket_007 alright man, just edited again.

Comment: Bingo, generator ran out of values.... This is why you include all the code, because I was about to say your list comprehension didn't modify the list

Comment: any solutions to generator exhaustion except reinitializing it everytime?

Comment: You could put your `for` loop inside `while True` in `get_examples()`, but the problem with that is that your `get_all_predicates` function will check each value within `examples`, and consequently will still exhaust the generator.  You could modify `get_all_predicates` to go only so far, but I think it is better just to reinitialize the generator every time.